# how to force header order in result of a select?

Tags: pandas, apache, apache-drill, pydrill

I developed 2 codes but the goal is the same.
The first, it submit a query to apache drill by pydrill. The query in this case is a lot of select comands and a union all between them, then I save the result in a dataframe.
The second code, it submit a lot of queries (each is a select) and I append the result in dataframe.
Both the solution doesn't respect the columns order.
For instance: select column[1] as A, column[2] as B
The result is a big dataframe and its header is B, A
In my case, the dataframe has 7 columns and the order is different then the clause select.
One of the columns is a fqn attribut (from apache drill) to get the path of current file.

Comment: What version of Drill do you have?

Comment: drill 1.15.0, pandas 0.23.4, pydrill 0.3.4 and python 3.7.1

Comment: I think it is an issue of PyDrill. Could you try the same query in Drill SqlLine or in Drill WebUI?